# Meaning of "nuage de fièvre" in French (part of song lyrics)

Tags: sens, paroles-de-chanson

What's meant by "nuage de fièvre" in French? Is it a cold cloud? Why using fever? Is it a poetic use?
I found it in the song *La où je t'aime* by Dalida ([lyrics](http://www.lyricsmode.com/lyrics...)), where she sings "[...] Un nuage de fièvre entre la Sologne et Paris..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means a feverish cloud and is just a metaphor.

> C'est une forêt vierge où les mots d'amour sont maudits
>  Un nuage
>   de fièvre entre la Sologne et Paris
>
> [The place where I love you]
>  It's an untouched forest where words
>   of love are damned
>  A feverish cloud between the Sologne region
>   and Paris

The structure of the entire song is built around the idea of *The place where I love you* is: a series of sentences describing that place. The Sologne is the place where all this bucolic ardor takes place.....The song is both happy and sad, as love typically is.

In short, the Sologne is a picture post card of ponds, forests and castles, as one site on the Internet puts it. The suggestion is that the lovers leave Paris and head to Sologne to be together and all along the route there is a feverish cloud over them as they rush to their romantic destination where this love is "realized".

Comment: Thank you very much for your long answer and explanation, that really clears it up!

Answer (score 2):

Beside, it might be a poetic metaphor in these lyrics, but it is not at all a "French expression": it was used nowhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I guess singers like Dalida could use whatever metaphors they'd like!

Comment: Everyone seems to be obsessed by what exists already and what has not yet been written. No one said it was a "French expression".  Thank goodness people can come up with new ways of saying things.

Comment: you are wrong, everyone is 'obsessed' for a reason: When a foreigner ask about an expression, it's crucial to tell him whether it is idiomatic or not (in addition to give a translation, which we did). OP asked "What's meant by 'nuage de fièvre' in French?" , strongly suggesting he could think it could be an idiomatic expression.

Comment: Yeah, sure a foreigner. Gotta watch out for them. It is a fact on language sites that beginners (language learners and translators) are constantly saying: I could not find x in the dictionary. That suggests these neophytes believe that everything is already "out there". This OP is more sophisticated than that and knew it was poetry right away. And I confirmed it in my answer. If one says, this is a metaphor, and then goes on to explain it at length, it's obvious it's not an idiom (idiomatic expression)..